# Is there such a thing as travel-sized organic kitchen detergents?

Tags: international-travel, food-and-drink, tips-and-tricks, hygiene

Besides filling up some dish-washing detergent in a travel-sized container on my own...I want to know if any companies sell pre-packaged packets or tiny bottles  of ***organic*** dish-washing liquid that kills bacteria etcetera?

Comment: Such thing exists, there are even some that can be used with several purposes like washing hair, etc to avoid taking several bottles. If those kill bacteria that is something different.

Comment: I got a travel-sized Dr. Bronner's but I'm looking for stuff that actually kills bacteria.

Comment: Dr Bronner's is fine!

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51961/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-liquid-soap-to-wash-dishes-when-travelling?rq=1

Comment: You can use Sea to Summit's "Wilderness Wash" to wash dishes, clothes, and yourself. Not sure of any antibacterial stuff though, as it's supposed to be biodegradable. The little bottles travel well and are leak proof (but due to the nozzle design you can't refill them).

Comment: I think that "organic" and "antibacterial" is a sort of oxymoron. Why do you want something that's organic, if you want to kill bacteria? I guess it depends on your definition of organic, but you can probably only have one or the other.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options. In Amazon there is a keyword when looking for dish detergents called [travel size](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_in_-2_p_n_location_browse-_10?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A3760901%2Cn%3A!3760931%2Cn%3A15342811%2Cn%3A15693761%2Cn%3A15342851%2Cp_n_location_browse-bin%3A5255345011&bbn=15342851&ie=UTF8&qid=1444984058&rnid=2707783011). A quick look in Google also gave results like [this one](http://www.minimus.biz/Dish-Detergent.aspx).

Comment: None of them are organic though. It's tougher finding ANYTHING organic.

Comment: @verve Is organic a deal-breaker for you? If so we should probably edit the question title to make it stand out.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is what you suggest in your first sentence: get a travel-size container of your own and fill it up with washing up liquid. For completeness sake [travel-sized containers must be of a volume ≤ 100ml / 3.4 fl.oz](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/liquids-rule).

The first thing that comes to mind is to recycle existing containers. Off the top of my head I am thinking of reusing one of those hand-sanitizer containers of the type that people commonly carry with them when winter falls in fear of being contaminated with the flu. Being pocket-/purse-sized they might fall under the travel-sized category too. The other option is to purchase one of the many travel-sized container kits one can find ([see here for several Amazon listings](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=travel%20size%20container)), and fill one of the containers with washing-up liquid.